# Привязка объекта к shape, изменяемому в Expression Controls (After Effects)

Tags: графика, adobe, expressions, motion

Есть Shape (Rectangle), для которого параметр Size изменяется с помощью слайдера в Expression Controls и есть ещё один объект (Start Window), который должен изменяться в соответствии с изменением Rectangle.

Если изменять параметр Scale для Rectangle, то Start Window также изменяется (так как привязан к Rectangle через стандартную привязку), но для того, чтобы изменять Shape корректно, я использую параметр Size (content("Rectangle").content("Rectangle Path").size).

При изменении параметра Size привязанные стандартным образом объекты не меняют положение и размер.

Подскажите, каким образом можно привязать объект Start Window к Rectangle, чтобы при изменении параметра Size для Shape, пропорционально изменялся объект Start Window (как при стандартной привязке, только без искажения объектов)?

Можно запутаться, но я прикрепил скриншоты, надеюсь поможет.

[image: скриншот1]

[image: скриншот2]

Answer (score 0):

Подсказали на другом форуме:

```
s = thisComp.layer("Start Window").transform.scale;
x = thisComp.layer("Start Window").content("Rectangle 2").content("Rectangle Path 1").size[0]/2/100*s[0];
y = thisComp.layer("Start Window").content("Rectangle 2").content("Rectangle Path 1").size[1]/2/100*s[1];
[value[0] + x, value[1] + y]
```